# Razorpay signature missing in response

Tags: reactjs, signature, razorpay

I'm trying to implement razorpay in my react app. in response of the handler I was receiving the `razorpay_signature` but from yesterday I'm not receiving the `razorpay_signature` in the response. I've done some research and a lot of people are saying you must pass the order id. I've verified I'm passing the order id in the options. In the response I can see the status is captured. does that payment was successful. can we skip the signature? what will be the consequences? did razorpay changed their response Is that a possibility?

```
{
  key: process.env.REACT_APP_RAZORPAY_KEY_ID,
  amount: data.amount_due,
  order_id: orderId,
  ...
  handler: async (res) => { ... }
}
```